# Angular 4 : " Set Cookie " flag in Http response is not setting Cookie in browser

Tags: angular, setcookie, angular-httpclient, angular-http-auth

I'm working on a Website using **Angular 4**.
We are using Cookie authentication method.
After login process API response have **cookie** in **Set Cookie** field. But its not setting value in browser. So authentication of other APIs get failed.
While using postman its working fine. Following is the Angular code using http get method ( this Api is created for testing purpose.)

```
this.http.get(
'http://test.xxx.com/test/testjsondata/login', 
{ withCredentials : true}
) 
.map(res => res.json()).
subscribe(data => {   console.log(data); });
```

[image: Chrome console of api][image: Cookies in Api response][image: Cookies are not added in browser]

Comment: How can we fix the same issue in angular 4